# INSERT value by adding URL and file name

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-insert

I want to to insert value into my single column with website URL and upload path. But I'm really don't doing that. Here I have 2 columns into my table. And I want to insert the website URL and upload path into 2nd column `$website_logo`. Need to be output like this: `https://website.com/uploads/image.png` below provided my code:

```
// insert new data to menu table
        $sitelink = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]";
        $sql_query = "INSERT INTO tbl_category (website_link, website_logo)
                        VALUES('$website_link', '$sitelink'/'$website_logo')";
```

`$sitelink` will get the website URL with HTTP. But it's not working for me. How I can do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Considering 'tbl_category' is MySQL table name and $website_logo holds value 'image.png':

```
$sitelink = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]";
$logo = $sitelink . '/uploads/' . $website_logo;
$sql_query = "INSERT INTO tbl_category (website_link, website_logo)                  
              VALUES('$sitelink', '$logo')";
```

Comment: you are great! is this not violate to adding links?

Comment: it's not inserting the image name and extension. why you are not added that?

Comment: As mentioned, I have considered that $website_logo has value 'image.png'. Can you please brief your question?

Comment: thanks dear... i was forgot to provide my all code. now i'm edited my real code with your's. now it's working perfectly.